# configure zts on mac+xampp

Tags: php, macos, xampp, pthreads

I need to use pthread in one of my project and I am using XAMPP on mac. When I try to install pthread using this commend "sudo pecl install pthreads", I get this error "pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled". I tried to google about enabling zts on mac+xampp, but there is not much help. Almost every topic says to reinstall php version with zts enabled. But there is not much help available. Please help.